# How can I solve error of "Fail to fetch" resulting of apt-get update on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt, php, ssl, certbot

I've got a issue that stuck me on Debian 8 Jessie when I try to upgrade to Debian 11 Bullseye
Trouble seems come from old version of Letsencrypt certbot that I have uninstall but I still got some trouble about it.

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:        8.11
Codename:       jessie
```

Here is content of sources_list file

**nano /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
```

**apt-get update**

```
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
    
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
    
    W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
    
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**apt-get upgrade**

```
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main libpcre3 amd64 2:8.43-1+0~20190710.6+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.43-1+0~20190710.6+debian8~1.gbpbfc49f_amd64.deb  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've already try some apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean and apt-get autoremove which runs without error

**apt-get autoremove**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4281 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone have some clue to help me to solve this issue ?

**Edit :
After removing of useless files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I got this :**

**apt-get update**

```
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**apt-get autoremove**

> E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/growroot failed with return 1.
> update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-10-amd64 with 1.
> dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
> installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit statu 1 Errors were encountered while processing:
> initramfs-tools E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
> (1)

**SOLVED :
Delete content on /etc/apt/sources.list.d**

Comment: Looks like the errors are coming from package repo and PPA entries that aren't in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.   Do you have files in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory?  Are those file intended to install packages for Debian?  (at least one error mentioned a PPA for Ubuntu rather then Debian)

Comment: Indeed there was many useless files on /etc/apt/sources.list.d
Once removed, I only get "server certificate verification failed"after apt-get update (full error on edited question)

Comment: The site `packages.sury.org` uses an SSL/TLS certificate that's signed by the `Let's Encrypt` Certificate Authority (CA).  Your `apt-get` command says it doesn't have the Let's Encrypt root certificate in its collection of trusted certificate authorities.  How recently have you upgraded the `ca-certificates` package?  I wonder if Debian Jessie may be too old to have the Let's Encrypt root certificate in it.

Comment: Thanks, I have remove everything on /etc/apt/sources.list.d and I was able to upgrade from Debian 8 to Debian 11 even if it's really not recommanded