# Missing dependencies after migration to Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg, mariadb

After update to Debian 11, I got this error message

**apt-get upgrade**

```
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-core (= 0.140) but it is not going to be installed
     libfcgi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.32.0
     libmodule-build-perl : Depends: libperl-ostype-perl
                            Recommends: libarchive-tar-perl
     mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Depends: libmariadb3 (>= 10.5.4) but it is not going to be installed
     mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.38-0+deb8u1) but it is not installable
     perl : Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.20.2-3+deb8u12)
     php-xml : Depends: php7.4-xml but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

**apt-get -f install**

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libmariadb3 which isn't installed
Selecting previously unselected package libmariadb3:amd64.
dpkg: considering removing mariadb-server-10.0 in favour of libmariadb3:amd64 ...
dpkg: mariadb-server-10.0 is not properly installed; ignoring any dependencies on it
dpkg: yes, will remove mariadb-server-10.0 in favour of libmariadb3:amd64
(Reading database ... 47493 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.prerm: line 12: invoke-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.0.postinst: line 265: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems to be a cache error but I don't really know how to fix it

Does anyone have any clue ?

**EDIT :**

Before trying to restore my server, I try to reinstall init-system-helpers but it seems to be already well installed and I don't know if this is the right version or to upgrade it

**dpkg -l init-system-helpers**

```
ii init-system-helpers 1.22 all helper tools for all init systems
```

**EDIT 2 :**
Fixed with those commands

*wget http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/init-system-helpers/init-system-helpers_1.60_all.deb*

*dpkg -i init-system-helpers_1.60_all.deb*

**dpkg -l init-system-helpers**

```
ii  init-system-helpers 1.60         all          helper tools for all init systems
```

**apt-get upgrade**

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmodule-build-perl : Depends: libperl-ostype-perl
                        Recommends: libarchive-tar-perl
 linux-image-3.16.0-10-amd64 : Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) but it is not installed or
                                        linux-initramfs-tool
 mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.38-0+deb8u1) but it is not installable
 perl : Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.20.2-3+deb8u12)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**apt-get -f upgrade**

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libmariadb3 which isn't installed
Selecting previously unselected package libmariadb3:amd64.
dpkg: considering removing mariadb-server-10.0 in favour of libmariadb3:amd64 ...
dpkg: mariadb-server-10.0 is not properly installed; ignoring any dependencies on it
dpkg: yes, will remove mariadb-server-10.0 in favour of libmariadb3:amd64
(Reading database ... 43777 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:53:38 CEST; 6ms ago
  Process: 28273 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:53:08 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Sep 16 16:53:08 vpsxxx mysqld_safe[28366]: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Sep 16 16:53:08 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:53:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1) starting as process 28370 ...
Sep 16 16:53:08 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:53:08 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[28652]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[28652]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[28652]:
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx mysql[28273]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:53:38 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
28370 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:54:10 CEST; 6ms ago
  Process: 28720 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:54:08 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:54:08 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:54:09 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:54:09 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:54:09 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:54:09 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29099]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29099]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29099]:
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx mysql[28720]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:54:10 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb ...
28817 28370 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:54:41 CEST; 7ms ago
  Process: 29157 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:54:40 vpsxxx mysqld[28371]: 220916 16:54:40 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:54:40 vpsxxx mysqld[28818]: 220916 16:54:40 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:54:40 vpsxxx mysqld[28818]: 220916 16:54:40 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29550]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29550]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29550]:
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx mysql[29157]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:54:41 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb ...
29264 28817 28370 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:55:12 CEST; 8ms ago
  Process: 29608 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:55:11 vpsxxx mysqld[28818]: 220916 16:55:11 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:55:11 vpsxxx mysqld[29265]: 220916 16:55:11 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:55:11 vpsxxx mysqld[29265]: 220916 16:55:11 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29997]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29997]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[29997]:
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx mysql[29608]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:55:12 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb ...
29715 29264 28817 28370 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:55:43 CEST; 7ms ago
  Process: 30055 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:55:42 vpsxxx mysqld[29265]: 220916 16:55:42 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx mysqld[29716]: 220916 16:55:43 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx mysqld[29716]: 220916 16:55:43 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30447]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30447]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30447]:
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx mysql[30055]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:55:43 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
30162 29715 29264 28817 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:56:14 CEST; 6ms ago
  Process: 30517 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx mysqld[29716]: 220916 16:56:14 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx mysqld[30163]: 220916 16:56:14 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx  mysqld[30163]: 220916 16:56:14 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30899]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30899]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[30899]:
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx mysql[30517]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:56:14 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
30614 30162 29715 29264 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:56:45 CEST; 5ms ago
  Process: 30967 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx mysqld[30163]: 220916 16:56:45 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx mysqld[30615]: 220916 16:56:45 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx mysqld[30615]: 220916 16:56:45 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31349]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31349]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31349]:
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx mysql[30967]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:56:45 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libmodule-build-perl_0.423100-1_all.deb ...
31064 30614 30162 29715 714
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmodule-build-perl_0.423100-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:57:17 CEST; 8ms ago
  Process: 31417 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 16:57:16 vpsxxx mysqld[30615]: 220916 16:57:16 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:57:16 vpsxxx mysqld[31065]: 220916 16:57:16 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Sep 16 16:57:16 vpsxxx mysqld[31065]: 220916 16:57:16 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31805]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31805]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: No such file or directory
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxxx /etc/init.d/mysql[31805]:
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxxx mysql[31417]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 16 16:57:17 vpsxxx systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mariadb-server-10.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.15-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.050-3+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-soundex-perl_3.05-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-7+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtext-charwidth-perl_0.04-10+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libparams-util-perl_1.102-1+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmodule-build-perl_0.423100-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You seem to have some packages intended for Debian 8 mixed in your Debian 11: `mariadb-server-10.0` and `perl`, at least. You might also be missing the `init-system-helpers` package. Try installing it first; that should fix the errors regarding `invoke-rc.d` and `update-rc.d`. Since your `initramfs-tools-core` is missing, your system might not be currently bootable with the Debian 11 kernel; if possible, don't reboot or shut down before fixing this and ensuring you have a valid initramfs file.

Comment: From OP's other question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717484/how-can-i-solve-error-of-fail-to-fetch-resulting-of-apt-get-update-on-debian-8 :   "I've got a issue that stuck me on Debian 8 Jessie when I try to upgrade to Debian 11" , ... " **I was able to upgrade from Debian 8 to Debian 11 even if it's really not recommanded**" . Upgrading from 8 to 11 without going through 9 and 10? What can be added?

Comment: Be sure to save your database contents and other valuable data somewhere else before you can't anymore.